# Are these graphs isomorphic ? Why?

Tags: group-isomorphism

[image]

Are these 5 vertex 5 edge graphs isomorphic ? Why ?

Comment: You should make the vertices more explicit in your drawing.

Comment: What is your definition of "isomorphic graphs"?

Comment: added vertices to the diagram

Comment: In the drawing at the right, swap the labels "C" and "D."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 5},
  DirectedEdges -> False];
```

[image]

```
    g2 = Graph[{"a" -> "b", "b" -> "c", "c" -> "d", "d" -> "a", 
   "d" -> "e"},
  DirectedEdges -> False,
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, g2]
```

True

Why?  Because there is a mapping from each vertex in g1 to a vertex in g2 that preserves all edges.